# Can we merge tags "tno" and "trans-neptunian-object"?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags

[trans-neptunian-object](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/trans-neptunian-object): Questions about objects orbiting the Sun with an average distance greater than that of Neptune. [24 questions]

[tno](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tno): A Trans-Neptunian object is any minor planet in the Solar System that orbits the Sun at a greater average distance (semi-major axis) than Neptune [14 questions]

To me, both of them is essentially the same thing. Can we merge the tags?

Comment: Done! ..........

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Status completed. Thank you called2voyage!